# The eigenvector does not minimize the error

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Consider the cost function J:

$J=|P_1-\beta P_2|^2+\lambda(\pmb{q}^H\pmb{q}-E)$

where $P_1, P_2$ and $\beta$ are complex scalars, $\lambda$ is the Lagrange multiplier and E is the constraint applied to the norm of the solution $\pmb{q}$, which is an n-by-1 vector. The first term of the function J defines the error that needs to be minimized. $\beta$ is just a fixed value. $P_1$ and $P_2$ depend on the solution as follows:

$P_1=\pmb{H}_1\pmb{q}$ and 
$P_2=\pmb{H}_2\pmb{q}$

where $\pmb{H}_1$ and $\pmb{H}_2$ are 1-by-n vectors

Introducing these expressions, J becomes:

$J=\pmb{q}^H((\pmb{H}_1-\beta \pmb{H}_2)^H(\pmb{H}_1-\beta \pmb{H}_2)+\lambda \pmb{I})\pmb{q} -\lambda E$

where $\pmb{I}$ is the n-by-n identity matrix. Note that the expression $(\pmb{H}_1-\beta \pmb{H}_2)^H(\pmb{H}_1-\beta \pmb{H}_2)$ is a n-by-n positive semidefinite matrix of single rank.

I'm not sure about next step but I would say that, since $\lambda$ is positive, the expression $((\pmb{H}_1-\beta \pmb{H}_2)^H(\pmb{H}_1-\beta \pmb{H}_2)+\lambda \pmb{I})$ can be considered positive definite and therefore a global minimum can be found by:

$\frac{\partial J}{\partial \pmb{q}}=0$

which leads to

$2((\pmb{H}_1-\beta \pmb{H}_2)^H(\pmb{H}_1-\beta \pmb{H}_2))\pmb{q}=-\lambda \pmb{q}$

The solution $\pmb{q}$ that minimizes the cost function is therefore the eigenvector corresponding to the minimum eigenvalue of $(\pmb{H}_1-\beta \pmb{H}_2)^H(\pmb{H}_1-\beta \pmb{H}_2)$. Since that matrix is rank 1, there is only one non-zero eigenvalue, so the solution is its corresponding eigenvector.

I tried and it turns out that the solution minimizes J but does not minimize the error $|P_1-\beta P_2|^2$. What am I missing? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It would be helpful to post the complete optimization problem. I'm not sure but $J$ seems to be the Lagrange-function and $|P_1-\beta P_2|^2$ should be the objective function but was is the constraint function?

Comment: @Ert You are right: J is the Lagrange function. The problem would be: minimize $|P_1-\beta P_2|^2$ subject to $\pmb{q}^H\pmb{q}=E$. Thanks again. I hope you can help me

Comment: So you have to minimize $|(\pmb{H}_1-\beta \pmb{H}_2)q|^2 $ subject to ${q}^H{q}=E$. For this problem, there are many solutions. Any vector $q$ that is orthogonal to $(\pmb{H}_1-\beta \pmb{H}_2)$ is a solution and can be scaled to satisfy ${q}^H{q}=E$. Your solution led to the maximization of the cost function as you picked the eigenvector corresponding to the only non-zero eigenvalue. However, the minimum eigenvalue is 0!

Comment: You don't have to look for non zero eigenvalue, the minimal eigenvalue is zero. So any vector orthogonal to $H_1-\beta H_2$ and scaled to have norm $E$ will be your solution.

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner Thank you guys